# Large list to dataframe with list identification in a new column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, events, identity

Using the example data "hourly_time_series" from IETD package,
I created a large list (each sublist are dataframes of different sizes) with IETD package. Each list represents a rainfall event.

```
library(IETD)
HU <- drawre(Time_series=hourly_time_series,IETD=5,Thres=0.5)
RE <- HU$Rainfall_Events
```

I need to convert RE to a dataframe with an additional column with the number of the rainfall event (as an ID) to separate them easily.
I tried with bind_rows() and rbindlist() functions but these don´t preserve the rainfall ID.
How Could I do this? The desired output as an example is:

| event | Date | depth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-01-06 04:00:00 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2000-01-06 05:00:00 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2000-01-06 06:00:00 | 1.5 |
| 1 | 2000-01-06 07:00:00 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 2000-01-06 20:00:00 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 2000-01-06 21:00:00 | 0.5 |
| . | . . | . |
| . | . . | . |
| . | . . | . |

Hope you could help

Comment: It will likely be very hard for folks to help you without reproducible data, please try to amend your question to include sample reproducible data.

Comment: Try `rbindlist(RE, idcol = "event")`

Comment: Dear @jpsmith , the reproducible data is the dataframe "hourly_time_series" that is part of the IETD package. I edited my question in the first line to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll define an example dataset for demonstration, a list called `ll` with five elements, each of which is a dataframe with two fields, `date` and `depth`. Each list element has a unique name, eg `event1`, `event2`, etc.

```
# Example data
ll <- list()
for(i in 1:5){
  df <- data.frame(
    date = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 100),
    depth = runif(100, 1, 5))
  ll[[paste0("event", i)]] <- df
}
```

You could add an ID field to each sublist and then collapse the list into a single dataframe:

```
# Define df ID for each list element
ll <- Map(cbind, ll, group = names(ll))

# Collapse list into single dataframe
res <- do.call(rbind, ll)

head(res)
               date    depth
event1.1 1999-04-09 2.174580
event1.2 1999-07-19 2.052316
event1.3 1999-10-23 4.890014
event1.4 1999-04-24 1.208217
event1.5 1999-10-20 1.946533
event1.6 1999-03-10 1.946779
```

Comment: Dear @Skaqqs Thank you so much. Could you do it using the "hourly_time_series" dataframe that is part of the IETD package as I put on the question code? with this dataframe I created the RE dataframe. The Map function doesn´t work for RE as it does for "ll". I edited the first line of the question to clarify the data used. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! I just tested my code with your new example data. The issue is that `RE` does not have names for each list element. Simply define names for `RE` (eg `names(RE) <- paste("event", 1:length(RE))`), and my code works perfectly with those data